# How to debug the Java compiler source code (Javac) itself?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I want to know the detail compilation process from the Java code to the bytecode, such as how a line Java code translate to the bytecode,so I want to set the breakpoint in the Java compiler source code, however I don't know how to do that , is there any reference or steps for that ?

BTW,
I don't ask how to use the Java debuger(obviously I know how to use it), I mean how to debug the Java compiler source code instead of the Java source code.

Comment: [Compiler construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is an advanced topic usually studied at universities etc. If you have no idea where to start, you likely lack most of the base knowledge needed to have any success with this project. Since the compiler is written in C++, you can't just "put a breakpoint" and see what happens.

Comment: @Kayaman:  I don't know what JavaC is written in, but whatever language it is written in surely has a debugger, and you *can* set a breakpoint.  I've done this zillions of times in my own compilers.  That is hardly the only technique for debugging them.

Comment: @IraBaxter Eh, I was mistaken. Javac is indeed written in Java, not C++ (like the JVM). So this question is half compiler construction and half how to use a debugger. I do know that other languages have debuggers. I just don't believe it matters if the starting point is so low.

Comment: Please adjust the title of your question. HotSpot doesn't compile Java source code to bytecode - HotSpot is part of the JVM and performs compilation from bytecode to native machine code.

Comment: No, I don't ask how to use the Java debuger, I mean how to debug the Java compiler source code instead of the Java source code. I mean I compile the Java source code by the Java compiler with source code model, which I get from the JDK with compiler source code , so I can set the breakpoint in the source code of Java compiler itself instead of the Java code.

Comment: Getting the Java source code and setting a debugger in it is the easy part (although you may have some issues importing it into your IDE) - you can find at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/ . But you need to understand compiler structure and tooling first, and the Java compiler specifically, or else you won't be having much fun in your debugging session.

Comment: Javac is a Java application, just debug it like you debug any other Java application, there's nothing magical here. Don't think in terms of "I want to debug the compilation of my code", think of it as "I want to debug this random application called Javac, and the input I debug it on happens to be this source code that I recently wrote in Java".

Comment: @Erwin, it is hard for me to get  URL explaining how to set the debugger with source code in IDE such as intellJ Idea or eclipse from hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools , can you help to give me the exactly URL?

Comment: @Oak, Suppose I download th JDK source code which has the javac source code, then I built it and import the source code to the IDE,then I opened the source code with IDE successfully,  however how to set the imported compiler with source code  as the debugger used by the IDE such as eclipse ,or intellJ idea?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I studied a bit by myself and I find two ways to debug the Java compiler source code. The easier way is to download the langtools code and configure the `${langtools_home}/src/share/classes` into your JDK source path. As `javax.tools` and `com.sun.tools` contains all the classes you need, so you can set breakpoint in classes from those packages. In Java 8, the Java compiler has been released into `tools.jar`. Above Java 9, it has been released into `jdk.compiler` module. You don't need to compile the compiler source code by yourself, unless you want to do changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question about how the compiler works is too broad to answer here.  Go read a standard compiler text book.

Regarding debugging a compiler:

I tend to heavily use assertions in the compiler (self-diagnosing) and large suites of small target language test programs focused on various language features that self-verify their correct functioning. (My last compiler has around a thousand of these test programs built over a period of 10 years, and a script to compile and run them all).  Often a failure of an assertion or a test hints to me where the compiler is wrong and mere inspection identifies the bug.

I often add special code to dump out key information about the state of the compiler and traces of activities that I can enable with special undocumented command line switches.   These special dumps indicate where the compiler goes astray, and again often enable code inspection to identify the location of the bug.

Failing that, I use a debugger for the language in which I have written the compiler.

I don't consider these techniques as particularly special.  They are useful when trying to work with any large, complex application.

Comment: I  didn't ask how the compiler works  ,I asked how to set the breakpoint in the Java compiler itself(Suppose we have the source code for the Java compiler  when we compile the Java source code )

Comment: @Hermas: that's funny, you said *I want to know the compilation process from the Java code to the bytecode*.   Most people would interpret that as "you want to know how the compiler works".  If that wasn't your question, you didn't express it very well.  If you want to know how to "set breakpoints" in JavaC, I suggest you get a Java development tool and learn how its debugger sets breakpoints. Why is this unobvious?

Comment: I obviously know how to set the breakpoints for the Java code in th IDE like eclipse or idea, however how to set the breakpoints for the JavaC? It means you first need to import the JavaC with source code to the IDE, then set the JavaC with source code as the default debugger, however how to do that two steps?

Comment: JavaC is *just* a program, just like any other.  If can you set up another Java program and can debug it, why can't you set up Javac and debug it?

Comment: How to choose the Javac with source code(getting it by downloading the JDK 7.0 source code ) from as IntellJ Idea as the default debugger, can you tell me the steps?

Comment: Nope. Java isn't my turf.  Some things you have learn on your own, have you read the documentation or tutorials completely?   The fact that you are struggling with starting up a debugger suggests that you are probably not ready for the complexity of digging into a compiler.  Have you actually studied a compiler book?  You aren't going to debug your way into knowledge in this area.  I'm done here.